# JTable throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException during paint

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel, indexoutofboundsexception

Hi I'm building an application using a `JTable` to display data from a database and I keep getting an `IndexOutOfBoundException` from `tableModel.getValueAt(row,col)` during painting. I debugged the code and it seems like the data isn't being saved to the `DefaultTableModels` data vector.

This is my code...

```
    public class TableFrame extends JFrame{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            TableFrame frame = new TableFrame();

        }

        private TablePanel tablePanel;
        public TableFrame(){
            super();
            setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            tablePanel = new TablePanel();
            add(tablePanel);

            updateLabels();
            setVisible(true);
        }

        public void updateLabels() {
            setTitle("Main Frame");

            tablePanel.updateLabels();
        }

        private static class TablePanel extends JPanel{

            private DefaultTableModel tableModel;
            private DefaultTableColumnModel colModel;
            private JTable table;

            private JPanel buttonPanel;
            private JButton refreshButton;

            public TablePanel(){
                setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        refreshButton = new JButton();
        refreshButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                refreshData();
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(refreshButton);
        add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //TODO:Set the column renderers and editors
        colModel = new DefaultTableColumnModel();
        colModel.addColumn(new TableColumn(0,75));
        colModel.addColumn(new TableColumn(0,75));
        colModel.addColumn(new TableColumn(0,75));
        colModel.addColumn(new TableColumn(0,75));
        colModel.addColumn(new TableColumn(0,75));
        colModel.addColumn(new TableColumn(0,75));
        colModel.addColumn(new TableColumn(0,75));
        colModel.addColumn(new TableColumn(0,75));
        colModel.addColumn(new TableColumn(0,75));
        colModel.addColumn(new TableColumn(0,75));
        colModel.addColumn(new TableColumn(0,75));

        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();

        table = new JTable(tableModel,colModel);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        updateLabels();
    }

    //This is going to query data from a database and populate the table
    //problem occurs during painting
    public void refreshData(){
        Random rand = new Random();

        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
            Vector<Object> fields = new Vector<Object>();
            for(int j=1;j<=11;j++){
                fields.add(rand.nextInt());
            }
            tableModel.addRow(fields);
        }
    }

    public void updateLabels() {
        colModel.getColumn(0).setHeaderValue("Col 1");
        colModel.getColumn(1).setHeaderValue("Col 2");
        colModel.getColumn(2).setHeaderValue("Col 3");
        colModel.getColumn(3).setHeaderValue("Col 4");
        colModel.getColumn(4).setHeaderValue("Col 5");
        colModel.getColumn(5).setHeaderValue("Col 6");
        colModel.getColumn(6).setHeaderValue("Col 7");
        colModel.getColumn(7).setHeaderValue("Col 8");
        colModel.getColumn(8).setHeaderValue("Col 9");
        colModel.getColumn(9).setHeaderValue("Col 10");
        colModel.getColumn(10).setHeaderValue("Col 11");

                refreshButton.setText("Refresh");

                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the exception...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:447)
at TableFrame$TablePanel.refreshData(TableFrame.java:108)
at TableFrame$TablePanel$1.actionPerformed(TableFrame.java:64)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2012)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2335)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:404)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6268)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6033)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2045)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4629)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2103)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4455)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4633)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4297)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4227)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2089)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2517)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4455)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:649)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:96)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:608)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:606)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:116)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:622)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:620)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:619)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
```

I debugged the code and added a call to `tableModel.getDataVector().getElementAt(0).getElementAt(0)` and `tableModel.getRowCount()`. `getRowCount()` returned `1000` but `getElementAt()` resulted in the `IndexOutOfBounds` exception, just like in the awt event queue. I think what I did should work but obviously there's something I'm missing.

Comment: The exception tells you where it happens exactly (line 108 of TableFrame.java), but it doesn't tell us because the code throwing the exception is not the code you pasted here: `refreshData()` never calls `Vector.getElementAt()`.

Comment: I can't answer post the whole stack trace but here's the topException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
 at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:447)
 at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:650)
 at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2719)
 at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5719)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2108)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2010)

Comment: Just figured it out. I never called tableModel.setColumnCount() so the tableModel justified the data to the number of columns it knew about. I thought the tableModel had knowledge about the column model but apparently it doesn't. I'm not allowed to post an answer for the next two hours but I'll do so as soon as I'm allowed.Thanks for checking out the question JB.

Answer (score 1):

The `TableModel` doesn't refer to the `ColumnModel` to get the number of columns so this has to be set using `tableModel.setColumnCount()`. Otherwise the `defaultTableModel` justifies the data and truncates the row to the number retreived by `getColumnCount()`.